# Layering softmax classifier into RNN autoencoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, autoencoder

The paper I'm implementing is using an RNN with autoencoder to classify anomalous network data(binary classification). They first train the model unsupervised, and then they describe this process:

> Next, fine-tuning training (supervised) is conducted to train the last layer of
> the network using labeled samples. Implementing the fine-tuning using
> supervised training criterion can further optimize the whole network. **We use softmax regression layer with two channels at the top
> layer**

Currently, I've implemented the autoencoder:

```py
class AnomalyDetector(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AnomalyDetector, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
            layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),
            layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"),
            layers.Dense(16, activation="relu"),
            layers.Dense(8, activation="relu")])

        self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
            layers.Dense(16, activation="relu"),
            layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"),
            layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),
            layers.Dense(79, activation='relu')
        ])
```

**How do you implement the softmax regression layer in TensorFlow?**

I'm having trouble understanding the process, am I supposed to add another layer to the autoencoder? Am I supposed to add another function to the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone in the future visits this -
You can create a softmax layer by changing the activation. I chose a sigmoid activation in my case since sigmoid is equivalent to a **two-element softmax**. As per the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/activations/sigmoid).

```py
class AnomalyDetector(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AnomalyDetector, self).__init__()
        self.pretrained = False
        self.finished_training = False
        self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
            layers.SimpleRNN(64, activation="relu", return_sequences=True),
            layers.SimpleRNN(32, activation="relu", return_sequences=True),
            layers.SimpleRNN(16, activation="relu", return_sequences=True),
            layers.SimpleRNN(8, activation="relu", return_sequences=True)])

        self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
            layers.SimpleRNN(16, activation="relu", return_sequences=True),
            layers.SimpleRNN(32, activation="relu", return_sequences=True),
            layers.SimpleRNN(64, activation="relu", return_sequences=True),
            layers.SimpleRNN(79, activation="relu"), return_sequences=True])
            layers.SimpleRNN(1, activation="sigmoid")
```

Comment: Thanks for answering you own question with what you finally found working, I hope it will help!